# What's causing the lag spikes to my ubuntu linux server node process

Tags: 18.04, server, ram, cpu, memory-usage

I run about 5-6 node processes related to [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/), and sometimes I get some lag spikes and some of my node processes are printing ''Killed'' and it's terminating their process. Why is that? [image]

here is my ram usage (i was asked)

[image]

Comment: Check your RAM usage, too.

Comment: @user535733 i will edit my question with a ram photo too

Comment: Well, there's your answer. Your choice is to add more RAM or to run fewer RAM-hungry processes.

Comment: It's quite obvious from your RAM graph that your RAM nears 100% and the kernel kills the hungry process in order to prevent OOM. You can see the cut-off at ~01:50